# En référence à URL: La URL ou l'URL ?

Tags: pronoms, informatique

Quand nous utilisons l'acronyme `URL` (pour [Uniform Resource Locators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)), est-ce acceptable d'utiliser l'article
*l'* devant `URL` lorsqu'utilisé dans une phrase, de la manière suivante:

- l'URL

ou il est préférable de dire

- la URL
- une URL

Qu'en pensez vous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est toujours *l'URL*, abréviation où les trois lettres sont prononcées séparément:  /ly.ɛʁ.ɛl/. On peut aussi bien sûr dire *une URL*.

Comment: Est-ce qu'il y a une sorte de règle qui existe pour les pronoms qui devraient être utilisés (pour les acronymes avec lettres prononcées séparément) comme dans cet exemple?

Comment: @marsisalie C'est toujours *l'*, comme pour n'importe quel mot français commençant par un U. Par contre, personnellement quand je prononce à l'anglaise (donc U prononcé "you") j'ai tendance à ne pas faire la liaison, comme en anglais (*"an idea"* mais *"a unique idea"*). Donc je dirais "Le PDG *de* United Airlines". Mais cet usage est très minoritaire et je ne peux pas le recommander.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Compris - tel qu'amené dans la réponse ci-haut je m'attendais à une règle particulière avec les acronymes,

OK - on y va comme cela!